# Tomcat remote access

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-7

I'm really new in using of tomcat server.

I have installed it on Windows 7 VM and i want to have access on it from my phisical host. 
I have read many topic on "how to gain access in tomcat remotely" but nothing.

Please help me ,  I already spent a week on it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all answer. 
I have resolved my issue.

My problem was that i had not permit the remote access to 8080 port on my Windows VM.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you can access your tomcat server internally. You can check it by using your web browser: http://localhost:8080/ (8080 is a default http port on tomcat).

Secondly, find out your VM ip address, for instance, 192.168.254.10 (just sample). You can get it by command line: ipconfig/all.

Finally, using your browser from your laptop or other VM that have same network to access: http://192.168.254.10:8080